# Rounded border around a selection of grid cells (running into edge cases)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, svg

I'm attempting to use HTML to define the tiles of a game.
There are multiple players, but borders denote who owns each group.

In vue, I'm using this function to handle creating the borders. the `up` `down` `left` and `right` variables denote whether or not a field has a neighbor of the same group in that direction.

```
const calcBorder = computed(() => {
  const { up, down, left, right } = props.field.border;
  return `border-width: 5px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  border-color: ${props.field.color};
  border-top-style: ${up ? 'none' : 'solid'};
  border-left-style: ${left ? 'none' : 'solid'}; border-right-style: ${right ? 'none' : 'solid'};
  border-bottom-style: ${down ? 'none' : 'solid'}; border-radius: ${up ? '12px' : 0};
  background:${bg};
  border-radius: ${!up && !left ? '12px' : '0'} ${!up && !right ? '12px' : '0'} ${!down && !left ? '12px' : '0'} ${!right && !down ? '12px' : '0'};
`;
});
```

I'm starting to think, however, that I might need to do this with SVG or something. Originally we were doing it with canvas but the problem is that it's not possible to zoom in without pixelation. As you can see, there are edge cases (ie between F8 and G9) that I dont think are possible with stock CSS.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can re-approach this issue?

[image: edge cases]

Comment: Is the problem about identying the tiles that must have this little corner border? Or is it about how to write the style for it with css?

Comment: I dont think borders in CSS can work in those corners. I'm trying to think of how this can be done by dynamically generating an SVG or something

Comment: You can using pseudo elements like `:before`, absolutely positionned in the corner. Make it a square of n px (the size of the border) with a border-radius on one corner and it's done!

Comment: An approach suited for SVG would be to collect "fragmented" paths. First, define all the lines to be drawn at the border of each group. Then, identify where lines of the same color meet at the same corner. If you connect them all correctly, the end result will be a number of closed polygons. Last step would be then to draw the correct curve (or straight connection) in each corner.

Comment: @Kapcash that is slick. How could I have not thought of this hack haha

Comment: Since my original border code that I was trying to replace was in context2d canvas, I wound up going the route of finding a library that could serialize canvas's context2d methods into an SVG. I tried a few libraries and I ended up using red-agate-svg-canvas. I tried canvas2svg, fabric.js, d3-path, but none of them seemed to implement context2d as well as red-agate.

Comment: It's funny, of course, literally every part of that implementation.. every layer of the game converted flawlessly with red-agate except the borders had some mild imperfections. https://i.imgur.com/vZ5SaEi.png 

I might try that `:before` concept if I want to give it another go.